# WildFly Equivalent of JBoss Singleton Scheduler

Tags: jboss, singleton, wildfly, scheduler

In JBoss 4, Singleton scheduler was achieved through 'org.jboss.varia.scheduler.SingleScheduleProvider' MBean and *-service.xml. How to achieve the same in WildFly 21?

After following HA Singleton Deployer guide, I came to conclusion that we can only make the entire application (EAR/WAR/JAR) singleton in a cluster but not a specific scheduling service with in the application.

For example, 1 scheduler service needs to be Singleton where as other scheduler service needs to run on all the nodes in a cluster.

Comment: https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/11.x/ha-singleton-deployment looks like what you want.

Comment: @stdunbar this is for deploying entire module as singleton i.e. EAR, JAR or WAR. I am looking for a specific component to be Singleton inside JAR

Answer (score 0):

Structure your scheduler service as a JBoss MSC service, and use the singleton service facility as described here: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/_high-availability/ha-singleton/Singleton_MSC_services.adoc